# How to show error message after server response?

Tags: forms, vue.js, validation

I have these two form fields in my vue wordpress theme.

```html
                <!-- telefono -->
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                    <label class="mt-3 mb-1">Telefono</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="+39" v-model.lazy="store.prefisso" id="phonePrefix">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" :class="{'is-invalid': !store.telefono || store.invalidPhone, 'is-valid': store.telefono }" placeholder="3212345678" v-model.lazy="store.telefono" @change="checkPhoneNumber" @blur="checkFormFields" id="phoneNumber">
                    </div>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        <small v-if="!invalidPhone">Required field</small>
                        <small v-if="invalidPhone">Insert a valid phone number</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- email -->
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                    <label class="mt-3 mb-1">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': !store.email || invalidEmail, 'is-valid': store.email }" placeholder="Email" v-model.lazy="store.email" @blur="checkFormFields" @change="checkEmail">
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        <small v-if="!invalidEmail">Required field</small>
                        <small v-if="invalidEmail">Insert a valid email address</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I've implemented in a custom plugin a validation system for the email address.

When the user insert it and leave focus from the field, I need that if the email address or the phone are invalid, it will add the custom error message and the bootstrap class `is-invalid` or if all is ok, `is-valid`.

At the moement in my code I've added a data property that is called `invalidEmail` and `invalidPhone` and they are set using this two methods

```js
        checkPhoneNumber(){
            //console.log('checkPhoneNumber')
            const res = phoneValidator(`${this.store.prefisso}${this.store.telefono}`)
            //console.log(res)
            if( res.isValid() ){
                this.store.invalidPhone = false
            } else {
                this.store.invalidPhone = true
            }
        },
        checkEmail(){
            axios.post(`${wp_params.resturl}validate-email`, {
                email: this.email
            },{
                headers: {
                    'X-WP-Nonce': wp_params.nonce
                }
            }).then( (res) => {
                console.log(res.data)
                //{
                //    "valid_format": true,
                //    "valid_mx_records": false,
                //    "possible_email_correction": "dave@gmail.com",
                //    "free_email_provider": false,
                //    "disposable_email_provider": false,
                //    "role_or_business_email": false,
                //    "valid_host": false
                //}
                //let parsedResponse = JSON.parse(res.data)
                console.log(this.store.invalidEmail)
                if( res.data.valid_format === true && res.data.disposable_email_provider === false && res.data.valid_mx_records === true ){
                    this.store.invalidEmail = false
                } else {
                    this.store.invalidEmail = true
                }
                console.log(this.store.invalidEmail)
            }).catch( e => console.log(e) )
        }
```

How I can accomplish this? At the moment the `v-if` I've added seems not working as expected.

Comment: Does it work if you set the this.store.invalidEmail in the catch block? `.catch(e => this.store.invalidEmail = true)`?

Comment: didn't tested this solution, I think the problem is with the dynamic classes I try to set?

Comment: @Djave tested, but not working